# how to calculate user last active time?

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can we calculate login time(or user last active time), if user hit on "Remember me" option than how can get their login time(because user is already in session/Logged-In and user login time is same ,when user login with remember me option) ?

Comment: While submitting login form, save the current time in Database.
While logout, add a flag that this is logged out.

Comment: thanks,
also i got window focus function to find who is online at a same time.

Answer (score 0):

you can set last activity of user / login time in a database table, than you can read from that to get all data.

Hope I help you.
Marco

Comment: i have set 'last login' time in database ,but problem is that when user is already in session (using remember me option ) than how can get their last active time ?